# Sending Django email with image content

Tags: python, django, html-email

I am trying to send email with image using:

```
subject = 'Material Requests System'
        html_message = render_to_string('app/mailing/email.html', {'request': request})
        plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
        from_email = 'blablabla0'
        to = 'blablabla1'
        mail.send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [to], html_message=html_message)
```

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static/img')
]
```

my `email.html`:

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<img src="{{ request.get_host }}{% static 'img/logo.svg' %}" alt="" />
{% endblock %}
```

[my explorer solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExCyG.png)

But when I receive an email - it doesn't consist any image.
Only:
[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7uCR.png)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Email clients can't access your server's static files. They need a full URL to an image that's hosted online. So, the image source should be a full URL, not a relative path.

You first need a public URL for your images, then, you can use that in your email template. So instead of {% static 'img/logo.svg' %}, you would use something like https://your-server.com/static/img/logo.svg.

However, keep in mind that this approach requires your server to be publicly accessible and properly configured to serve static files, which might not be ideal or feasible in all situations.

You can also consider hosting your images online using a cloud storage service such as AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage, or a separate image hosting service to host your images.